# "I will know more after I study than I know now ?" Is it ok to use "more after I study than" in the sentences?

Tags: word-order, clauses

I know adj can come between more and than but I don’t know why the clause can replace in adj position.

Comment: Your phrase would be easier to understand as “I will know more than I know now after I study”, keeping the "knowledge" related phrases next to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic statement is

> I will know more ... than I know now.

**after I study** is  adjunct info and yes, it can come between **more** and **than**.

The phrase can also begin the sentence or end it:

> After I study I will know more than I know now.
>
> I will know more than I know now after I study.

You can also do that when **more** modifies a noun:

> They watched more TV **in one week** than he watched in a year.
>
> In one week they watched more TV than he watched in a year.

This is awkward and a little confusing but not ungrammatical:

> They watched more TV than he watched in a year, in one week.

Comment: I understand it more but I have got confused between a phrase and a clause. I think that it will be a clause because it accompanies by Subject and a verb (I think it is Adverb clause). Is there something wrong about my understanding? thankyou.

Comment: You're right, there is a verb there, and a subject, and it is a clause. It is temporal. The idea could also be expressed using the present perfect: *after I have studied*.